# Use one or multiple SKScenes for Level based Game

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm making a level based game using SpriteKit. I would like to know the best practice for making level changes. I was originally using one Scene as my gameplay scene and when a level is completed, it removes all nodes in the scene and then adds the ones for the next level. I am using a background node that is persistent throughout the entire course of the game. I'm worried about memory because I don't think ARC will deallocate the nodes removed because the scene is persistent. Is this method ok or should I instantiate a new scene for when a level is changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to separate game data and assets from game code. This way, you can make changes to stuff without having to recompile (and is handy if you are working with another person who doesn't code).

Here is what apple has to say about it at WWDC 2014:
[image: :]

---

When you transition between scenes, ARC will deallocate the prior scene, assuming you made no strong references to it. Since you're starting out it's unlikely you need to worry about this right now... it's mostly done with globals and closures, and you should be able to fix it *if* it becomes a problem (but likely won't).

You can use things like `unowned self` and `weak var` etc to ensure this doesn't happen when needed. Again this is a more advanced topic but it's good to be aware of them.

Really, making level changes is entirely up to you... if you want to make a state manager that swaps out stuff to one scene, you can certainly do that... or, you could make a bunch of scenes and transition to that. Again, the best practice here is separating game content from game code, not necessarily how you switch scenes.

Personally, I would used separate `SKScenes`-- because it's already built in with transitions, memory management--and you have the option of using the editor, and you get to give each scene it's own file if desired.

There is also `GameplayKit` which has a statemanager, in which case you could use one scene and have different states be the level.

here are some resources, buried in there are some nuggets pertaining to what you want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/608/

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DemoBots/Listings/DemoBots_SceneManager_swift.html